# Hide password protected posts in admin

Tags: posts, password

I'm building a site for a client and we're using WordPress' native password protect functionality.

Is there a filter or some kind of action to filter posts retrieved in the administration panel? If I want to stop all password protected posts from being displayed in the admin panel, lets say if you're not an administrator.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [`has_password`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Password_Parameters) parameter of `WP_Query`.

Here's an example how you can hide it, for non administrators, on the `edit.php` screen for the *post* post type:

```
/**
 * Hide password protected posts, for non-admins, in the case of 'edit-post' screen id
 *
 * @link http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/200426/26350
 */
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', function( \WP_Query $q )
{
    $screen = get_current_screen();

    if(    is_admin() 
        && ! current_user_can( 'manage_options' ) 
        && is_a( $screen, '\WP_Screen' ) 
        && 'edit-post' === $screen->id
    )
        $q->set( 'has_password', false );
} );
```

Hopefully you can adjust this to your needs.

PS: it would be handy to have a `get_current_screen_id()` function, similar to the  `get_current_user_id()` function ;-)

### Update

```
/**
 * Hide password protected posts, for non-admins, in the case of 'edit-post' screen id. 
 * Here we don't restrict this to the current user.
 *
 * @link http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/200426/26350
 */
is_admin() && add_action( 'posts_where', function( $where, \WP_Query $q )
{
    $screen = get_current_screen();

    if(     
           ! current_user_can( 'manage_options' ) 
        && is_a( $screen, '\WP_Screen' ) 
        && 'edit-post' === $screen->id
    ){
        global $wpdb;
        $uid = get_current_user_id();
        $where .= $wpdb->prepare(
            " AND ( ( {$wpdb->posts}.post_password = '' AND {$wpdb->posts}.post_author != %d )
              OR ( {$wpdb->posts}.post_author = %d ) ) ",
            $uid,
            $uid
        );
    }
    return $where;
}, 10, 2 );
```

### If `WP_Query` would support `field_query`:

It would be handy if `WP_Query` would support the `field_query` input argument, to make it easier to work with the post fields.

Here's an example:

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', function( \WP_Query $q )
{
    $screen = get_current_screen();

    if(    is_admin() 
        && ! current_user_can( 'manage_options' ) 
        && is_a( $screen, '\WP_Screen' ) 
        && 'edit-post' === $screen->id
    )
        $q->set( 'field_query', 
            [
                'outer_relation' => 'AND',
                'relation'       => 'OR',
                [ 
                    'field'   => 'author',
                    'value'   => get_current_user_id(),
                    'compare' => '=',
                ],
                [
                    'relation'  => 'AND',
                    [
                        'field'     => 'author',
                        'value'     => get_current_user_id(),
                        'compare'   => '!=',
                    ],
                    [
                        'field'     => 'password',
                        'value'     => '',
                        'compare'   => '=',
                    ],
                ]       
            ]
        );
} );
```

*I've a draft for such a plugin, so maybe I will post it here when it reaches the alpha stage ;-)*

Comment: Thanks a lot, I'll try this out in a few minutes. I thought edit.php was all post types? Is it possible to add this for all post types?

Comment: Somehow WordPress turns its familiar "white screen" on when entering the code.

Comment: Also is it possible inside pre get posts to determine the author of the post?

Comment: sorry about that, just forgot the quotes around `\WP_Screen`, just tested it and it works now @Dueify

Comment: what kind of author filtering do you mean? @Dueify

Comment: Well, it's because my client wants to hide all password protected pages in the administration area if you're not the author of the post. So I can't just hide all posts with a password if you're not admin, since the author of the post might not be an admin and they of course still will need access to the post. Does that make sense?

Comment: I've updated the answer @Dueify

Comment: Thanks a lot, birgire, I'll test everything, you have been a great help, and please post your plugin if it's ready in the future, I'd appreciate it :-)